# How to remove conditions from AR::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I wanna to use default_scope and remove all order conditions from it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`reorder` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder).

```
User.reorder('id DESC')
```